# What is the correct api to use for enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, enzyme

I am currently working on a react project with karma, enzyme as my test framework. I have gone through the enzyme document from: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md. In this document, it says that `to.have.equal` is the API to check a value. See below example.

```
expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.have.length(3);
```

but when I write my test cases, karma complains to is not defined. After some searching I have to use below code instead of `to.have.equal`.

```
expect(wrapper.find(Foo).length).toEqual(1);
```

The enzyme version is used is '^2.5.1'. Did I use a wrong version? Or the document is out of date? If so, where I can find the correct API document?

--EDIT1--
Below is the command I used to run karma:

```
./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start config/karma.conf.js --single-run --browsers PhantomJS
```

Below is the dependencies listed in my package.json file:

```
"devDependencies": {
"autoprefixer": "^6.3.6",
"babel-core": "^6.6.5",
"babel-eslint": "^6.1.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.11.5",
"babel-preset-airbnb": "^2.1.1",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.13.0",
"classnames": "^2.2.5",
"cross-env": "^1.0.7",
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"enzyme": "^2.5.1",
"eslint": "^3.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^5.2.2",
"eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"file-loader": "^0.9.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.10.0",
"jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
"karma": "^0.13.19",
"karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
"karma-browserify": "^5.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
"karma-mocha": "^0.2.1",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
"koa": "^1.2.0",
"koa-router": "^5.4.0",
"koa-serve-index": "^1.1.1",
"koa-static": "^2.0.0",
"koa-views": "^4.1.0",
"koa-webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.1",
"koa-webpack-hot-middleware": "^1.0.3",
"less": "^2.7.1",
"less-loader": "^2.2.3",
"loader-utils": "^0.2.16",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
"postcss": "^5.1.2",
"postcss-display-inline-block": "^1.0.0",
"postcss-easysprites": "^0.1.7",
"postcss-import": "^8.1.2",
"postcss-less": "^0.14.0",
"postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
"postcss-modules": "^0.5.0",
"precss": "^1.4.0",
"raphael": "^2.2.1",
"react-css-modules": "^3.7.6",
"react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
"rimraf": "^2.4.3",
"style-loader": "^0.13.0",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"webpack": "^1.12.9",
"webpack-dashboard": "^0.0.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
```

},

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "history": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.5",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1",
    "react-form": "^0.0.2",
    "react-paginate": "^2.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.4",
    "redux-router": "^2.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  }
```

Comment: Is Enzyme a test framework and Karma rendering framework?

Answer (score 0):

[Enzyme (and AFAIK the examples) was written with Mocha in mind:](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/mocha.md)

> Enzyme was originally designed to work with Mocha [...]

See the [Karma example](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/enzyme-example-karma/blob/master/test/Foo-test.js):

```
it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
  expect(mount(<Foo />).find('.foo').length).toBe(1);
});
```

As the [docs state](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/karma.md):

> Enzyme is compatible with Karma, but often requires a little bit of configuration.

Don't conflate test runners with rendering frameworks, or assertion libraries (like Chai) with either.

Comment: Does this mean the API 'to.have.length' is from Mocha and 'toEqual' is from Karma?

Comment: @ZhaoYi I'm not sure; for Mocha I use `chai` and I don't know where the dividing line is. `toEqual` the same, not sure if it's Karma or Enzyme.

Comment: I have checked the two examples 'enzyme-example-mocha' and 'enzyme-example-karma-webpack'. I found that in the test file from 'enzyme-exmaple-mocha', there is 'import {expect} from 'chai'' statement but there is no such state in the other example. Is this the different?